# TouchUpInside event not firing for the entire button frame

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uipickerview

I have simple button with image, it has fixed width and height of 110.

So the issue is that the touchUpInside event is only firing if I click on the top 20% on the button if click below that nothing is trigged not even a tap gesture on the button.

After searching, most of the solutions suggested that if a view block's the button's frame the touch event may not pass through, but I don't have anything of that sort of. The buttons are subview of the root view.

I also checked I don't have any gesture recogniser used on my View Controller.

So can anybody point me in the right direction to resolve this issue.

And this issue is happening with other standard UIControls as well (eg : DatePicker only the upper part of Picker view is scrollable the bottom part is not active)

Comment: Show your code what you have written or share the screenshots if UI is designed in XIBs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, your button is not fully in its superview. Make sure that the button's superview is larger than the button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer this was the issue. Changing the background color of the superview and checking it in the preview revealed the issue.

Comment: Try setting clip to bounds to true for the superview.